# Refine Query Results from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT routes.route_date, time_slots.name, time_slots.openings, time_slots.appointments
FROM routes
INNER JOIN time_slots ON routes.route_id = time_slots.route_id
WHERE route_date
BETWEEN 20140109
AND 20140115
AND time_slots.openings > time_slots.appointments
ORDER BY route_date, name
```

This works just fine and will produce the following results:

[image]

What I want to do is only return one `name` per date. So the 9th, name = 1, would only have 1 result, rather than 2, as it currently does.

Comment: I m not sure about your question, but will not `distinct` solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** See the SQLFIDDLE for different type of solutions here: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ac65b/6**

Will it solve your request if you use...

SELECT DISTINCT routes.route_date...*your query*... ?

It depends if you know that your rows always will have the same values, for same date/name.

Otherwise use group by...

(which I think suits your request best)

```
SELECT routes.route_date, time_slots.name, sum(time_slots.openings), sum(time_slots.appointments)
FROM routes
INNER JOIN time_slots ON routes.route_id = time_slots.route_id
WHERE route_date
BETWEEN 20140109
AND 20140115
AND time_slots.openings > time_slots.appointments
group by routes.route_date, time_slots.name
ORDER BY route_date, name
```

(i did a sum for the openings and appointments, you could do min, max, count, etc. Pick the one that fits your requirements best!)

Comment: Of course that the distinct applys the entire row, thats why I wrote if he knows that they will have the same values. Otherwise the results will be multiple names, if openings or appoinments differs for the different days. The group by is grouped by date and name, the rest will use an aggregate function. See answer.

Comment: Adding the `SELECT DISTINCT` worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to figure out which "name" you want when there are several for the same date.
2. Then you can group by date and select the right "name" by using an aggregate function like `COUNT`, `MAX`, etc.

I can't help you more if you don't explain your rule for picking one.

Comment: The rule for picking one is really which ever come first. I don't care which one I get, I just need one. I've already isolated everything, and now I just want to refine the results.